# Interpretation the BIC score graph

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, gmm

I have a plot with BIC scores: number of components and type of covariance matrix. It has some values positive and others negative. I do not know how to interpret them. I need to choose n_components and type of covariance matrix for constructing GMM model.

I can't add an image here, so i add the link:

BIC graph

[image: BIC graph]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are multiple things in the graph, which part of it isn't clear?

Comment: I don't understand the negative part. Because I did another graph and I have all positive values where with the sign "*" you can see the number of components and type of covariance matrix. But here I see that I have the number of components 7 and type is diag but in negative values. How does it influence when you build the GMM model (have negative or positive values)?